# Get specific char from a string request

Tags: c#, substring

I need to get 4 variable from a string

That's a resquest someone can make to a server :

```
String request= "Jouer_un_bulletin <nbT> <mise> <numeros_grilleA> <numeros_grilleB>"
```

I need to get `nbt`, `mise`, `numeros_grilleA` and `numeros_grilleB`

Comment: how does the `string Jouer_un_bulletin` related to the 4 results?

Comment: @Ian There was and issue qith the post. I replaced <> with " " now

Comment: you better edit the question as it is and then make the `< >` visible by writing it as code (press ctrl +k )

Comment: @Ian Thanks I've changed it !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using *regular expressions*:

```
  String request = "Jouer_un_bulletin <nbT> <mise> <numeros_grilleA> <numeros_grilleB>";

  String pattern = @"(?<=<)[^<>]*(?=>)";

  String[] prms = Regex
    .Matches(request, pattern)
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Test:

```
  // nbT
  // mise
  // numeros_grilleA
  // numeros_grilleB
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, prms));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the request.  How to do this is entirely based on what you expect to receive and how you validate it.  Assuming (and this is a big assumption) that you will always get the format above, you can use String.Split to split the string on the open bracket character, and then take the component pieces (ignoring the first one) and trim off the close bracket and any additional spaces.  These will be your variables.  This is not, by any means, a good way of sending data, and you should at a minimum validate this data a lot before using it.

The very basic (and by all means this is terrible code you shouldn't use) concept is:

```
 String request= "Jouer_un_bulletin <nbT> <mise> <numeros_grilleA> <numeros_grilleB>";
 var pieces = request.Split('<');
 var strList = new List<string>();
 for(int i = 1 ; i < pieces.Length; i++)
 {
     strList.Add(pieces[i].Trim(' ','>'));
 }
```